# embed normal html form in sencha ext js application

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs4

Currently we have a big component (feature) that written in normal HTML (just one page) & Javascript (pure JS + JQuery). It's very difficult or impossible to rewrite by Sencha EXT JS.
And we are developing a new application entirely in Sencha.

Is there anyway that I can embed this feature into the new Sencha application that left the original source code (HTML + JS) intact?

Thanks!
MillDol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a complete html page with a [`Ext.ComponentLoader`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentLoader).

```
var cmp = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    loader: {
        url: 'myPage.html',
        renderer: 'html' //default
    }
});
```

If you already have the content in javascript you can use.

> Ext.getCmp('yourComponentId').[update(theHtmlorData, [loadScriptsOnPage], [callback])](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-update)

where yourComponentId is an element with an id (not recommended to use id's)

Comment: Thanks A1rPun. I will try and come back later!

Comment: So, in the html page I have script tag to load my js files, and it will function as normal, right?

Comment: Yeah but you need to add the `scripts:true` config to the Loader to make this work.

Comment: scripts:true is just for inline js. What i want is js files specified in <script> tag will be loaded with the html just like a normal page. Can we achieve this? Thanks.